# sugarcrm: unable to call login from custom soap service by extending existing webservice

Tags: sugarcrm

I am following this tutorial to extend the Sugarcrm webservice to define the new service for my custom module.
**Problem: But, as a preliminary check, I tried to call the existing login service and that itself fails. Please help in pointing where the issue is.** I am stuck.

Tutorial I am following: http://support.sugarcrm.com/02_Documentation/04_Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_6.5/02_Application_Framework/Web_Services/06_Extending_Web_Services/

As mentioned in the tutorial, I created the following files in the folder, custom/service/v4_1_custom

**registry.php**

```
<?php
require_once('service/v4_1/registry.php');
class registry_v4_1_custom extends registry_v4_1
{
    protected function registerFunction()
    {
        parent::registerFunction();
        $this->serviceClass->registerFunction('my_get_orders',
        array(
                'session' => 'xsd:string',
                'module_name' => 'xsd:string',
                'id' => 'xsd:string',
        ),
        array(
                'return' => 'xsd:string',
        )
        );
    }
}
?>
```

**soap.php**

```
<?php
if(!defined('sugarEntry'))define('sugarEntry', true);
    chdir('../../..');
    require_once('SugarWebServiceImplv4_1_custom.php');
    $webservice_class = 'SugarSoapService2';
    $webservice_path = 'service/v2/SugarSoapService2.php';
    $registry_class = 'registry_v4_1_custom';
    $registry_path = 'custom/service/v4_1_custom/registry.php';
    $webservice_impl_class = 'SugarWebServiceImplv4_1_custom';
    $location = 'custom/service/v4_1_custom/soap.php';
    require_once('service/core/webservice.php');    
?>
```

**SugarWebServiceImplv4_1_custom.php**

```
<?php

    if(!defined('sugarEntry'))define('sugarEntry', true);
    require_once('service/v4_1/SugarWebServiceImplv4_1.php');
    class SugarWebServiceImplv4_1_custom extends SugarWebServiceImplv4_1
    {
        /*
         * Returns the  id if authenticated
         *
         * @param id 
         * @return string $session - false if invalid.
         *
         */
        function my_get_orders($session, $module_name, $id)
        {
            $GLOBALS['log']->info('Begin: SugarWebServiceImplv4_1_custom->my_get_orders');
            $error = new SoapError();

            //authenticate
            if (!self::$helperObject->checkSessionAndModuleAccess($session, 'invalid_session', '', '', '',  $error))
            {
                $GLOBALS['log']->info('End: SugarWebServiceImplv4_1_custom->my_get_orders.');
                return false;
            }
            return $id;
        }
    }
?>
```

My webservice client for testing the webservice: SoapTest.php

**SoapTest.php**

```
<?php
if(!defined('sugarEntry'))define('sugarEntry', true);
require_once('../include/nusoap/nusoap.php');  //must also have the nusoap code on the ClientSide.


$user_name ='myuser';
$user_password = 'mypassword';
$hostname = 'http://127.0.0.1/sugarcrm/custom/service/v4_1_custom/soap.php?wsdl';

// Create the SOAP client instance
$soapclient = new nusoapclient($hostname, true);
// Login to the server
echo '<b>LOGIN:</b><BR>';
$result = $soapclient->call('login',array('user_auth'=>array('user_name'=>$user_name,'password'=>md5($user_password), 'version'=>'.01'), 'application_name'=>'SoapTest'));


echo '<BR><BR><b>HERE IS RESULT:</b><BR>';
echo print_r($result);
echo var_dump($result);
$session = $result['id'];


echo "sessionid is ".$session;
?>
```

Expected Result: Since I am calling the login, i expect to see the sessionid.

*Note: I am not calling the custom method `my_get_orders` as the login itself fails. So i like to fix it first.*

Actual Result: [while invoking `http://127.0.0.1/sugarcrm/prash/SoapTest.php`]

```
HERE IS RESULT:
1
boolean false
sessionid is
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put the same set of files under service/custom [ The existing versions are directly under service/   eg : service/v4_1 ].

Now it works, so earlier it was the case of file path resolving issue.